# Can I use construction adhesive on these fake rocks?

Tags: fireplace, adhesive, rock

Our fireplace has fake rocks made of some kind of foam and mortar. We are installing a mantle, and want to use construction adhesive and bolts to anchor it.

What are the “rocks” made of? Will the solvents in the construction adhesive mess with it?

[image: fake rock]
[image: scale reference]

Comment: Why are you using construction adhesive, and not some form of mortar?  If the bricks are foam, it sounds like they might just be largely a veneer, and not strong enough to hold up a mantel.

Comment: The rocks are definitely veneer, but they’re mortared together. I assume it’s all attached to some kind of blue board backer.

Comment: Why do you assume that? Any proof?

Comment: No proof, that just seemed like a normal way to install them. Would you expect something else?

Comment: This type of stone is typically a cast concrete, not foam, especially if it is being used around a fireplace where non combustible material is a must. Is the dark places where the paint or colorant was scraped off? I have seem "pumice" like stone too like foam, but crumbly.

Comment: @Jack That airy stone doesn't look like any cast concrete I've ever seen.  It does, however look similar to pumice.  I'd agree it's unlikely to be foam.

Comment: Whatever your course is, I wouldn't use construction glue.  Construction glue isn't intended to get hot.  If you think you can somehow tie into this thing, the mortar is the best bet, and more mortar is the best bet to secure any bolts.  The project sounds a bit iffy though.  I'd do some tests with drilling a spot, anchor, mortar, wait a couple weeks for the mortar to cure, and see how hard you can pull on it.

Comment: @SteveSether, mortar may not be the best thing, but you are right about a test hole if the OP intends on putting a mantle no matter what it takes. It could still be a veneer over wire lath, then mortar will not be the fix. If it is a natural pumice stone, laid with cement, then perhaps an epoxy in the large tubes with the mixing nozzle may be best injected into drilled holes to anchor a few posts. Still, natural pumice stone is rather dense, this does not appear to be so...

Comment: it doesn't look entirely unlike AAC, the Bubble size seems a lirrle reguiar for pumice, but a little irregular for AAC,  the colour mix is unlike pumice

Comment: @Jasen I'd never heard of AAC before, but AAC would match what you need for a fireplace.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoclaved_aerated_concrete